# OpenBSD: stop resolvd from prepending nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns, dhcp, openbsd

After upgrade to 7.1
I notice that `resolvd` always adds a nameserver received via dhclient to /etc/resolv.conf

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf                                                                                           
nameserver 10.0.2.3 # resolvd: vio0
lookup file bind
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

That's unexpected behaviour, because `dhclient` is configured to supersede DHCP's DNS configuration.

```
$ cat /etc/dhclient.conf                                                                                         
supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

Comment: resolvd's entire purpose is to automatically bugger up your resolv.conf, so if you don't want it to do that, don't run it.

Comment: seconding @cas : I said good bye to a whole lot of grief once I switched to a static resolv.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dhcpleased was introduced around 7.0 (see release notes).  This means that the configuration should be done through it's configuration.

In your case create the file /etc/dhcpleased.conf

```
interface vio0 {
    ignore dns
}
```

Reference: https://man.openbsd.org/dhcpleased.conf